# split scrapy output to different columns

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Here I have a scrapy script, and I added one field called 'name'. I extract data in a list, so now, I don't know how to split this list, so each element is in one column in the same row. So for example, here I should have 100 columns and one row.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import ScholarItem
from urllib.parse import urlparse,parse_qs


class SchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'sch'
start_urls = ["https://scholar.google.com/citations? 
                hl=en&user=ccfU5GoAAAAJ&view_op=list_works&sortby=pubdate&cstart=0&pagesize=100"]

def parse(self, response):
    item = ScholarItem()
    names = []
    ls = response.xpath("//tr[@class='gsc_a_tr']")
    for i in ls:
        if int(i.xpath(".//span[@class='gsc_a_h gsc_a_hc gs_ibl']/text()").get()) > 1999:
            names.append(i.xpath("./td[@class='gsc_a_t']/a/text()").get())
        else:
            break
    item['name'] = names
    yield item
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'columns' here? Do you want to insert every element from the 'names' in a separate column in a database?

Comment: Yes, every element in a seperate column in csv output file.                                                    @WimHermans

Comment: Iterate the names list, and in each iteration create a `ScholarItem` instance, assign the corresponding name to it, and yield that instance.